# wso2 product Registry menu (config, governance, local)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is there any authoritative documentation available for data found under the Registry UI menu (for example as found in WSO2 ESB admin screens)?

I have seen snippets of information about this registry, for example:

> The configuration registry contains product specific configuration
> that can be shared across multiple instances of the same product (a
> cluster of ESB nodes for example).
>
> Source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9712962/howto-access-registry-in-wso2-esb)

To start with, I have a few questions:

1. What is the difference between this registry and the WSO2 Governance Registry?
2. What are the typical use cases for a WSO2 esb admin user for interacting with this Registry?
3. What are the typical use cases for a WSO2 esb developer for interacting with this Registry?
4. Is there a description of all the meta data stored in this registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In All WSO2 products there is an internal registry which is used to store resources. WSo2 Governance Registry uses the same core features + some more feature that gives complete Governance scenario. If you need you can mount to an external WSo2 Governance Registry without using the internal registry you referred.You can find more details [here](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances).

Comment: Thanks Shelan - that link answers questions 1,2.  However, I'm still a bit sketchy on questions 3 and 4.

Comment: There are several ways a developer can benefit using Governance registry.If you consider registry as a repository to store your resources you can store wsdls, policies and schemas which can be reused and manage through it. There are many like that [http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com/2012/07/wso2-esb-proxy-from-registry.html] this includes one such example. Metadata can be varied and it depends on the requirements and IIRC there is no documentation for it. But as in the link i shared in my answer, there are 3 main partitions in the registry and have logical separation for their concerns.