# How to use the wsdl in wso2esb with addition operation

Tags: wsdl, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb4.7.0, I tried with database working fine I wrote the proxyies without  publish wsdl option so those working fine .There is no operations publishing that is fine.
Now I wish to publish the operation, for that I wrote a sample wsdl and I place it in my local system downloads folder. When I am importing into proxy its unable to import, if I give any wso2dss wsdl with this url:`192.168.1.14:8282/services/user?wsdl`  the service is working fine and publishing operations also but I dont want to use that wso2dss opeartions, I wish publish my own operation how could I do this
my wsdl file like this

```
<definitions name="HelloService"
   targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/Addition.wsdl"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/Addition.wsdl"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <message name="SayHelloRequest">
      <part name="var1" type="xsd:integer"/>
      <part name="var2" type="xsd:integer"/>
   </message>
   <message name="SayHelloResponse">
      <part name="result" type="xsd:integer"/>
   </message>

   <portType name="Hello_PortType">
      <operation name="sayHello">
         <input message="tns:SayHelloRequest"/>
         <output message="tns:SayHelloResponse"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>

   <binding name="Hello_Binding" type="tns:Hello_PortType">
   <soap:binding style="rpc"
      transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
   <operation name="sayHello">
      <soap:operation soapAction="sayHello"/>
      <input>
         <soap:body
            encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
            namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
            use="encoded"/>
      </input>
      <output>
         <soap:body
            encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
            namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
            use="encoded"/>
      </output>
   </operation>
   </binding>

   <service name="Hello_Service">
      <documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
      <port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
         <soap:address
            location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello/">
      </port>
   </service>
```

and I am storing this into this path
home/downloads/system/addtion.wsdl
but its not importing its giving errors 
where can I store this wsdl for importing into wso2esb

Comment: i wish to pass 2 numbers and expacting those 2 numbers addition

Comment: You can add your WSDL in the registry, refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/9712962/2764076 for more details